# Reviving transition effects after they stop working

Tags: javascript, css

ok, if a transition is set on a style via CSS it works and keeps working as long as the style is not changed by Javascript (then the transition stops) even if the Javascript restores the original property to its former value.

Is there a way to revive a transition after a style has been "touched" ?

For example once the Javascript sets the width to the value of 100px (which was the CSS value) the transition stops.

```js
var el = document.getElementById("test");
el.style.width = "100px";
```

```css
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    -webkit-transition: width 2s; /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
    transition: width 2s;
}

div:hover {
    width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

Comment: Perhaps also worth reading: https://css-tricks.com/controlling-css-animations-transitions-javascript/

Comment: @CBroe: Thanks for the link !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you hardwire the width with `el.style.width = "100px"`, that overrides your `div:hover` CSS rule so it will no longer have precedence.

You need to increase the precedence of the `:hover` CSS rule so that it will still take effect.  You can do that a number of ways.  One way of doing that is with `!important`.  Normally, I don't like using `!important`, but in this case, it's hard to override the precedence of a directly assigned style without it.

```
div:hover {
    width: 300px !important;
}
```

You can read about how the CSS specificity is calculated [here](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/) to determine what gets precedence.  Unfortunately for you, a directly assigned style rule has very high precedence.

Here's a working demo:

```js
var el = document.getElementById("test");
el.style.width = "100px";
```

```css
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    -webkit-transition: width 2s; /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
    transition: width 2s;
}

div:hover {
    width: 300px !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you. Although I do not yet fully understand why the "hover" is overridden; its width is a separate entry in the style sheet.

Comment: @ThomasAn - If you read the CSS specificity link I provided in my answer, it will explain how the browser decides which CSS setting gets applied when there are multiple settings attempting to control the same property.  In your case, you have three settings all trying to control the width, the `div` rule in your CSS, the `div:hover` rule in your CSS and the direct style setting on the element.  Those are all competing.  The CSS specificity calculation for each rule determines which has higher precedence.  As you had it, the direct style property setting wins with a higher CSS specificity.

Comment: I guess it is the logic that trips me at the moment. When we set the CSS div width and then set the div:hover, technically these two compete with one another too, but it still knows to apply the hover effect ... yet if we modify the width, all of a sudden it can't resolve that the hover is still on. I suppose it wants to have the :hover re-specified via Javascript every time one of its components change somewhere else. (provided I want to avoid using the !important hack)

Comment: @ThomasAn -  `div:hover {width: 300px}` has higher CSS specificity than `div {width: 100px;}` so, when `div:hover` is active, it wins the contest.  But a directly applied style has a higher CSS specificity than either of those CSS rules so it wins every time.  CSS specificity is a formula.  You calculate the CSS specificity value for each competing CSS setting and the highest one that matches a given element wins.  You really should read the link I provided or any other you can find with Google to understand how CSS specificity is calculated.

Answer (score 2):

You can overwrite the inline style with `!important`

```
div:hover {
    width: 300px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't stop per se, JavaScript simply placed the width as inline CSS which has highest specificity (except `!important`) and so the hover width will not work because its specificity is weaker. One workaround is using `!important` but I would not recommend this. Try removing the JS style or working with class transitions

```js
var el = document.getElementById("test");
el.style.width = "100px";
```

```css
div {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background: red;
    -webkit-transition: width 2s; /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
    transition: width 2s;
}

div:hover {
    width: 300px !important;
}
```

```html
<div id="test"></div>
```